# Parametric plot of a function which cannot be explicitly calculated

Tags: plotting, functions

I wish to plot a function, but I run into a problem and I cannot find similar questions here. A simplified version of plot is represented by

```
ParametricPlot[{g,f[x,y]}, {x,a,b},{y,c,d}]
```

`f` is quite a tricky expression and cannot be explicitly calculated for unknown `x` and `y`. Hence this plot does not work, as I believe Mathematica first explicitly calculates `f[x,y]` and then thereafter substitutes `x` and `y` in order to plot this. However, how can I do this such that `f[x,y]` substitutes the explicit values for `x` and `y` into `f`, as then the function can be calculated? For example, `f[1,2]` works absolutely fine, `f[x,y]` is the problem.

edit:

My code:

```
 cc = 0.4;
 cD = 0.1;
 r = 10.2;
 Nstar = Floor[r];

rhos1[N_] := (1 - N/r)*Lambda^N*
     Exp[eps]*Delta;
rhos2[N_] := (1 - N/r)*(Lambda*Exp[g])^N*
     Exp[eps]*Delta*Exp[g*Nstar]

rho = Sum[rhos1[n], {n, 1, Nstar}] + 
   Sum[rhos2[n], {n, Nstar + 1, Infinity}];
phi = Sum[n*rhos1[n], {n, 1, Nstar}] + 
   Sum[n*rhos2[n], {n, Nstar + 1, Infinity}];


phi3[Delta_] := 
       Sum[n*(1 - n/r)*\[CapitalLambda]^n*
         Exp[\[Epsilon]]*Delta, {n, 1, Nstar}] + 
       Sum[n*(1 - n/r)*(Lambda*Exp[g])^n*
         Exp[eps]*Delta*Exp[g*Nstar], {n, Nstar + 1, 
         Infinity}];

RhoDivided3 = Simplify[rho/Delta]

h1 = cD/(RhoDivided3 + Exp[g]);


f[eps1_, g1_] := Apply[List, Reduce[cc == 
  ReplaceAll[phi3[h1] + Lambda*
     Exp[eps], {eps -> eps1, 
    g -> g1}] && Lambda > 0 && Lambda < 
  0.99999, Lambda], {0, 1}][[2]]

Plot[ReplaceAll[phi/rho, {Lambda -> f[-2, g], 
         eps -> -2}], {g, -30, -10}]
```

Therefore `f` is obtained by solving a very complex equation for `Lambda`, and so cannot be determined as a function of epsilon and `g`, as explicit values are required.

Comment: Try `ContourPlot`! Please provide your code, this will increase your chance to get helpful answers!

Comment: Thanks, contourplot doesn't work though, as the problem remains the same

Comment: `f[1,2]` doesn't evaluate! `\[CapitalLambda]` isn't defined.

Comment: Excuse me, I thought I had changed all my \[CapitalLambda] to Lambda when I pasted my code here, but I forgot one. That's supposed to be Lambda